# How to read a single line out of a word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

The method I used was for text files and gives gibberish as expected.

```
In: John Smith
Out: PK!~8ìz‡­[Content_Types].xml ¢( ´”ÏNÂ@Æï&¾C³WÓ.x0ÆP8•D|€a;…Õvw³;ü{{§´5@UôBRf¾ß÷Ív;½Áº,¢%ú ­IE7éˆ²™6³T¼Lâ[“Aa
¦bƒAú—½ÉÆaˆXmB*æDîNÊ æXBH¬CÃ•ÜúˆýL:Po0CyÝéÜHe
¡¡˜*†è÷†˜Ã¢ h´æ¿ë$SmDt_÷UV©ç
­€¸,—&KÊÛ<×
```

I'm a novice at VBA, and I'm trying to read a document line by line so that I can eventually have the macro automatically remove entire lines based on their content.

```
Sub ayaya()
Dim TextLine As String
Open ActiveDocument.Path & "\Doc1.docm" For Input As #1
    Do While Not EOF(1) ' Loop until end of file.
    Line Input #1, TextLine ' Read line into variable.
    Debug.Print TextLine
    Loop
    Close #1


End Sub
```

Part of me hoped that it would give "John Smith". I've seen some solutions put the entire document into a text file. Is there any way where I can delimit the data somehow? I'd like to be able to isolate a single line and remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to read a docx or docm file, which is a zip archive. Word files are not plain text files, so you won't get anything meaningful treating them as such. You need to open the file with Word or another app that can read such files.